# Trying to Setup Log Monitoring with Sentry

Tags: monitoring, log-files, jboss

I am trying to setup a log monitoring application for monitoring Jboss Application logs. We have more than 50 Jboss Application servers in all our environments. My Requirement is below.

1. The log monitoring app should be open source.
2. There is less configuration required in client (Jboss) for fetching the log.
3. The app should capable of sending alerts to mail group.
4. It should be capable of detecting duplicate alerts.
5. We don't need to any kind of search or indexing of log data.
6. And also I want to filter Known Errors in the log, So that we dont get alerts for such errors.

We tried zabbix log monitoring but it has a lack of intelligence for detecting duplicate alerts.

After lot of Google search I heard about [Sentry](http://sentry.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html). I had configured the server successfully. But I don't know it is possible to monitor my Jboss application log with Sentry.?

Do anyone have experience in monitoring Jboss Application logs using Sentry?

Or there is any better open-source log monitoring app available which covers all my requirements above?

Comment: What do you mean by "detecting duplicate alerts"?

Comment: For example, if you happen to receive 100,000 events/second, and 10% of those are reporting a connection issue to the database (where they’d get grouped together). And the Monitoring app capable realizing that all those are same kind of error and only send 1 alert saying that "DB connection timeout occurred in 1000 times".
Ref : http://sentry.readthedocs.org/en/latest/buffer/index.html

Comment: -------------LOG------------------
2013-03-13 10:48:56,442 ERROR [nucleusNamespace.app.ecommerce.search.QueryFormHandler] (ajp-0.0.0.0-8239-71) beforeSearch() can not execute paged request with no previously saved request
-------------LOG------------------
I want to get all occurrence in the log except DEBUG and INFO.